# Multiple wireguard interfaces each using the 'real' interface directly, and through either be able to reach any IP

Tags: linux, wireguard

I'm in need of setting up multiple `wg-quick` interfaces on a single machine, both using the real ethernet NIC directly, independently.
The issue I appear to be hitting is that through each of these I want to access the entire internet, which I assume means `AllowedIPs = ::0`, but `wg-quick` likes to add routes locally such that all traffic going anywhere will go through this new interface; including any following `wg-quick` attempts..

Is there a way to call `wg-quick` and tell it "hey, no, I'd like you to use specifically `eno1`, not the 'default gateway'"? Perhaps using raw `wg`?

I've tried reading a bunch online but I keep getting confused what others are asking when it *seems* like a similar question, but turns out to be hosting multiple wireguard services or something.

Depicted below is the basic gist, with two wg interfaces. `wg0` in this instance is doing the normal `wg-quick` thing of stealing all traffic transparently, where `wg1` is an available interface where I can configure apps to specifically talk to it.
I don't mind if your solution has `wg0` being forced to work this way, I can set up a SOCKS and HTTP proxy for software that do not support "use this interface/IP for traffic" flags to get the same effect.

```
                                                             
      Home                ║      ISP       ║       Internet  
                          ║                ║                 
                          ║                ║                 
  ┌─────────────┐         ║                ║                 
  │             │         ║                ║                 
  │             │         ║                ║        ┌───┐    
  │             │         ║                ║     ╔══╪        
  │         eno1│         ║                ║     ║  └───┘    
  │   wg0      ┐│         ╙────────────────╜     ║  VPN0     
  │     ┐      └─────────────┘                   ║           
  │     ╞════════════════════════════════════════╝           
  │     ┘   ╔════════════════════════════════════╗           
  │   wg1   ║  ┌─────────────┐                   ║           
  │     ╓   ║  ┘│  router                        ║  ┌───┐    
  │     ╠═══╝   │         ╓────────────────╖     ╚══╪        
  │     ╙       │         ║                ║        └───┘    
  │             │         ║                ║        VPN1     
  │             │         ║                ║                 
  └─────────────┘         ║                ║                 
        PC
```

"Why?". Using openVPN my provider allowed open ports, basically local firewall permitting, I was publically routable and could host services on any number of ports I wanted. They've moved to wireguard, which is great, but they only support one open port per wireguard connexion. So basically for every app I had a port forwarded, I want to spin up a vpn interface for it.

Is this possible using just wireguard, no iptables or anything (which I dont understand at all)?

Comment: Look at the `Table` parameter in man wg-quick. The various requirements in your question (such as "including any following wg-quick attempts") doesn't let me attempt to do an answer.

Comment: so there's no way to ask `wg` to use a specific interface to initiate a connexion? Like, what if I had two interfaces, `eth0` and `wlan0` and the default route is through ethernet but the target wireguard server is only available via wifi, is that usecase just impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES. Okay. So the solution on the face of it really is as simple as `sudo ip route add $VPN1 via eno1` which will allow it to connect to VPN1 via eno1 regardless of wg0 existing. You are fully permitted to have multiple `::0` wg interfaces in the *same namespace* with one of them as default (wg0) so long as your applications support binding to an interface for connexions (like `netcat -s`). The caveat being only one such tunnel may be spawned with `wg-quick`'s `Table=auto`.

---

HOWEVER, what I've spent the last week fighting is the purpose of me wanting to do this in the first place; having those wg interfaces convey inbound traffic!

I tried multiple things;

- naively just running `wg-quick` multiple times with the route/s in place (this kills everything and attempting to `wg-quick down` breaks your network stack entirely)
- as above, spinning multiple up, one with `Table=auto`, the others with `Table=off`
- as above, spinning multiple up, one with `wg-quick`, the others with `wg`
- spinning multiple up with [`eno1` hiding behind a `namespace`](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/#the-new-namespace-solution) (I couldn't even get this to work for outbound traffic...)
- spinning multiple up with [each `wg` in their own `namespace`](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/#ordinary-containerization)

But even though these work [for outbound traffic down their respective tunnels] (unless otherwise noted) all of these refused incomming connexions (testing with `netcat -l -p $assignedPort`), regardless of `ufw disable` or using the same or different servers for "VPN{0,1}".

---

The solution here is something I [finally came across yesterday](https://serverfault.com/a/1126097/366157). The magic sauce `wg-quick` was doing with `Table=auto`; FwMark.

The thing I was trying to avoid learning how to do myself "Is this possible using just wireguard?". Well you do need the packets to be marked and associated with a table, BUT you don't need to understand/mimic/reimplement what `wg-quick` does...apparently you can just *use* it.

So, after setting up the default tunnel to VPN0 using `wg-quick` you take that FwMark and after setting the `ip route` for VPN1 **reuse that FwMark** for `wg`. This latter connexion now goes through eno1 (as per the route) but allows incomming packets forwarded from VPN1 (thanks to the Table set up by VPN0's tunnel).